# How do I return related entities in web api, and call web api from separate mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

How can I return an entity with it's related entities in a Web API method, and call it from a MVC application.

I have a Web API in which I am returning a `Person` entity, I am also returning all the policies linked to the `Person` entity.

So a `Person` can have one or many `Policies`.

So far I am able to do this in my Web API controller.

The problem is calling my Web API in a separate MVC application.

Currently I can only return the `Person` record in my MVC application, I am struggling to return the `Person` and all related `Policies` in my MVC application.

In my MVC `.cshtml` view I am calling the ViewModel to pass the data to all the fields in the Web API.

[This is my WebApi Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UFW7.jpg)

[Web Api ViewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqgsA.jpg)

[Policies Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNyXt.jpg)

[MVC Controller calling Web Api method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYNpT.jpg)

[This is the mvc cshtml view I am displaying the data from the web api in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x55yW.jpg)

```
    [Route("{pklifeinsured}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetRec(int pklifeinsured)
    {
        var model = new Amendments_Interface_VM();
        using (var db = new TestLiveEntities())
        {
            var ctx = db.LifeInsureds.Where(l => l.pkLifeInsured == pklifeinsured).FirstOrDefault();
            if (ctx != null)
            {
                model = new Amendments_Interface_VM
                {
                    pkLifeInsured = ctx.pkLifeInsured,
                    IdNumber = ctx.IdNumber,
                    Surname = ctx.Surname,
                    FirstName = ctx.FirstName,
                    Initials = ctx.Initials,
                    fkGender = ctx.fkGender,
                    DateOfBirth = ctx.DateOfBirth,
                    fkTitle = ctx.fkTitle,
                    fkMaritalStatus = ctx.fkMaritalStatus,
                    fkSmokerStatus = ctx.fkSmokerStatus,
                    fkLanguage = ctx.fkLanguage,
                    fkCommunicationMethod = ctx.fkCommunicationMethod,
                    Mobile = ctx.Mobile,
                    HomeTel = ctx.HomeTel,
                    EmailHome = ctx.EmailHome,
                    WorkTel = ctx.WorkTel,
                    EmailWork = ctx.EmailWork,
                    Postal_AddressLine1 = ctx.Postal_AddressLine1,
                    Postal_AddressLine2 = ctx.Postal_AddressLine2,
                    Postal_AddressLine3 = ctx.Postal_AddressLine3,
                    Postal_AddressLine4 = ctx.Postal_AddressLine4,
                    Postal_AddressLine5 = ctx.Postal_AddressLine5,
                    Physical_AddressLine1 = ctx.Physical_AddressLine1,
                    Physical_AddressLine2 = ctx.Physical_AddressLine2,
                    Physical_AddressLine3 = ctx.Physical_AddressLine3,
                    Physical_AddressLine4 = ctx.Physical_AddressLine4,
                    Physical_AddressLine5 = ctx.Physical_AddressLine5
                };
                model.PolicyHolder = db.PolicyHolders.Where(x => x.fkLifeInsured == pklifeinsured).Select(p => new PolicyHolderVM
                {
                    PolicyNumber = p.PolicyNumber,
                    DOC = p.DOC,
                    fkLifeInsured = p.fkLifeInsured,
                    PolicyStatus = p.PolicyStatus,
                    RelationshipToLifeInsured = p.RelationshipToLifeInsured,
                    Package = p.Package,
                    Name = p.Name,
                    ContactNumber = p.ContactNumber,
                    ID_Reg_Num = p.ID_Reg_Num,
                    EmailAddress = p.EmailAddress
                }).ToList();
            }
        }
        return Ok(model);
    }




public class Amendments_Interface_VM
{
    public int pkLifeInsured { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string fkTitle { get; set; }
    public string fkGender { get; set; }
    public string IdNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string fkMaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public string fkSmokerStatus { get; set; }
    public string fkLanguage { get; set; }
    public string fkCommunicationMethod { get; set; }
    public string WorkTel { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string EmailWork { get; set; }
    public string HomeTel { get; set; }
    public string EmailHome { get; set; }
    public string Postal_AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PA1_Id { get; set; }
    public string Postal_AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PA2_Id { get; set; }
    public string Postal_AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PA3_Id { get; set; }
    public string Postal_AddressLine4 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PA4_Id { get; set; }
    public string Postal_AddressLine5 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PA5_Id { get; set; }
    public string Physical_AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PhyA1_Id { get; set; }
    public string Physical_AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PhyA2_Id { get; set; }
    public string Physical_AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PhyA3_Id { get; set; }
    public string Physical_AddressLine4 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PhyA4_Id { get; set; }
    public string Physical_AddressLine5 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PhyA5_Id { get; set; }

    public IList<PolicyHolderVM> PolicyHolder { get; set; }

}




  public class PolicyHolderVM
{
    public int PolicyNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DOC { get; set; }
    public int fkLifeInsured { get; set; }
    public string PolicyStatus { get; set; }
    public string RelationshipToLifeInsured { get; set; }
    public string Package { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public string ID_Reg_Num { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}


        public ActionResult Index(int? pklifeinsured)
    {
        var LifePolicy = new Amendments_Interface_VM();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiURL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync($"{apiURL}/api/LifePol/{pklifeinsured}").Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                LifePolicy = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Amendments_Interface_VM>().Result;
            }
        }
        return View(LifePolicy);
    }
```

```html
@model WebApiTest_Invoke.Models.Amendments_Interface_VM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div class="panel-group" id="MainScreen">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainScreen" href="#collapse1"><strong>Policy Holder/s</strong></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PolicyNumber)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.PolicyNumber)
                    </td>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DOC)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.DOC)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fkLifeInsured)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.fkLifeInsured)
                    </td>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PolicyStatus)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.PolicyStatus)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RelationshipToLifeInsured)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.RelationshipToLifeInsured)
                    </td>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Package)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Package)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Name)
                    </td>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContactNumber)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ContactNumber)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID_Reg_Num)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ID_Reg_Num)
                    </td>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.EmailAddress)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainScreen" href="#collapse2"><strong>Life Insured</strong></a>
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "LifePol", FormMethod.Get))
                {
                    <p style="padding-left:700px;">
                        Policy Number: @Html.TextBox("pklifeinsured")
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                    </p>
                }
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surname)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Surname)
                    </td>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fkGender)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.fkGender)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.FirstName)
                    </td>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fkSmokerStatus)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.fkSmokerStatus)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fkTitle)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.fkTitle)
                    </td>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.DateOfBirth)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IdNumber)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.IdNumber)
                    </td>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Mobile)
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Mobile)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
  public Amendments_Interface_VM HttpClientCall(Amendments_Interface_VM value, string uri, int? pklifeinsured)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(apiURL) };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var httpresult = client.GetAsync(apiURL).Result;

        if(httpresult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = httpresult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Amendments_Interface_VM>(result);
            return data;
        }

        return new Amendments_Interface_VM();
    }
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub1wU.jpg)

Comment: Hey matey and welcome to SO! :) Can you add your code into the question? Images make it hard to try and figure out whats going on :)

Comment: Hi @garfbradaz, I have included the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a model as below in your mvc application and then call the api

```
public class YourModel
{
    public Person Person{get;set;}
    public List<Policy> Policies {get;set;}
}
```

and then make webapi method to send data in the same format as that of model, or you can even use thissame model in webapi for sending data.

now in your webapi controller:

```
YourModel data=new YourModel();
Person person=new Person();
person.name="test name";
.
.
data.Person=person;
Policy policy1=new Policy();
policy1.name="test name";
.
.
Policy policy2=new Policy();
policy2.name="test name 2";
.
.
data.Policies.Add(policy1);
data.Policies.Add(policy2);

return Ok(data);
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have the Policies property in you Person model and have it populated with necessary operation. Your model should look something like this. You can return all related entities by having entity property in the model.

```
    public class Person
    {
        /* public int Id { get; set; }
         * Other properties 
         */

        public List<PolicyHolderVM> policiesLst { get; set; }
    }
```

I have created function to call the API. This will return the Person object coming from the API.

```
    public Person HttpClientCall(Person value, string uri)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseUrl) };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var httpresult = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;

        if (httpresult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = httpresult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(result);
            return data
        }

        return new Person();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Aunell, I am already doing this in my WebApi project and it works fine.. Now  I am calling the WebApi project in a separate MVC project which is not connected to the database, so I need a ViewModel to pass all the data coming from the WebApi, and show it in a MVC cshtml view.

Comment: Hi @Auneell please see my code above, I hope this will give you better information regarding my question

Comment: @ZUKISABHOLOSHA You need to have the same class structure at you MVC project. API will return your data in JSON format so convert JSON to your object using NewtonSoft package like this for example "Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);"

Comment: I'm not sure where the above code  would go. Is it in my view or the mvc controller. Can you kindly give an example based on the above code structure.... The reason I'm asking is because the application returns the Person data to my mvc view, but not the Policy information.

Comment: @ZUKISABHOLOSHA I have updated my answer. Please have a look and let me know if that works for you or not.

Comment: Hi @Auneell I tried your function using my ViewModel class(please see above). It gave an error. I included the link to the error just below the code for the function.

Comment: @ZUKISABHOLOSHA How's the JSON looking? Look at the result variable. It may be throwing the error because JSON is not in correct format.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix this error, as it is a very vague error without any detail as to what is causing it. I've spent some time trying to fix it but it is taking me away from my other problem.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble for you, I can give you my WebApi url and you can test it on Postman. Then you can try and call it from a MVC application.

Comment: @ZUKISABHOLOSHA Sure provide the URL

Comment: I've got the application running on my side, so you should be able to run a Get request on Postman using that url.